# Distinguishing lowercase proper nouns in paragraphs

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, style-manuals, cmos

I'm writing a case study about a client whose name is completely lowercase. How do I differentiate the client's name from the rest of the text, making it clear to the reader that it's a proper noun? Italics? Quotation marks?

I'm following the Chicago Manual of Style in my writing, so if it offers any guidance on this topic, I'd prefer to follow that.

EDIT: To clarify, the client is a company, not a single person.

Comment: How can a proper noun not be capitalized? What makes it proper if it has no capitals?

Comment: @tchrist: would you say that e e cummings is a common noun? How about k. d. lang? But both of these are pretty obviously names, and so there's no need to set them in italics or similar. If somebody insisted on going by the name "serious matters", you might have the OP's problem.

Comment: @PeterShor And that's exactly the situation I find myself in. I can't reveal the name of my client, but it consists of two common nouns and the client insists on not capitalizing the name.

Comment: You could always precede it by mr. (or ms.).

Comment: @PeterShor The client is a company, not a person. (I should have specified that earlier.)

Comment: Just put "(tm)" after it.

Comment: The UNIX trade mark used to have very specific rules about how it should be typeset.  Perhaps yours might have always in italics, or always `font-size: 110%;`, or some such thing required.

Comment: There is a long, though by no means universal, tradition of using italics for marking out proper names, especially those of things other than people, in text.  Until you find better advice in the *Chicago Manual of Style*, follow that tradition.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I guess I'll go with italics for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a matter of style, not grammar. To start, *The Chicago Manual of Style* (17th ed.) does not say to use italics with the proper names of individuals or companies (unless specifically emphasizing the name as a word or phrase, for instance).

The following is what *Chicago* actually says about the various points that have been discussed in comments under the question.

*Chicago*, 5.6, ["Proper nouns"](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch05/psec006.html):

> A proper noun is always capitalized, regardless of how it is used—unless someone is purposely flouting the rules {k.d. lang}.

*Chicago*, 8.4, ["Capitalization of personal names"](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch08/psec004.html):

> Unconventional spellings strongly preferred by the bearer of the name or pen name (e.g., bell hooks) should usually be respected in appropriate contexts (library catalogs generally capitalize all such names). E. E. Cummings can be safely capitalized; it was one of his publishers, not he himself, who lowercased his name. Most editors will draw the line at beginning a sentence with a lowercased name and choose either to rewrite or to capitalize the first letter for the occasion. When a personal name includes a lowercase particle, the particle is capitalized if it begins a sentence or a note.

And, finally, *Chicago*, 8.69, ["Corporate names with unusual capitalization"](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch08/psec069.html):

> Corporate names that appear in all lowercase in logotype and other promotional settings can often be capitalized in the usual way. A copyright or “About Us” statement on a corporate website can be helpful in determining a usage that might be suitable for regular text. Words that would normally be lowercase in headline-style capitalization can usually be lowercased (see 8.159). Spellings that begin lowercase but include a capital letter are usually appropriate for running text, even at the beginning of a sentence, as are names with additional internal capitals (see 8.154). A preference for all uppercase should be respected. If a company appears to prefer all lowercase even in running text, an initial capital can be applied as a matter of editorial expediency.
>
> Intel (*not* intel)
>       Adidas (*not* adidas)
>       AT&T (*not* at&t)
>       Ebrary (*not* ebrary)
>       Parsons the New School for Design (lowercase *the*, contrary to corporate usage)
>
> *but*
>
> GlaxoSmithKline
>       HarperCollins
>       RAND Corporation
>       eBay

---

Having said that, before anything else, *do what the client says to do*. If the client's style is to use lowercase with their company name, then do so. It serves no purpose to go against their explicit wishes. (Although it would probably be a good idea to not start a sentence using their lowercase name.)

Only if the client does *not* express an explicit desire for the style to be used *and* if you want to follow *Chicago* style, then capitalize the company name as you normally would any other company name in running text—despite how it's normally represented otherwise. Also, use roman text rather than italics.

But should you decide to use lowercase text anyway, then the way to make it explicit that it's a company name, rather than a normal word or phrase, is from context. Write the sentence so it's obvious that it's the name of the company being discussed.

Finally, barring any other guidance, specific situations can overcome general guidance. If you do something that results in the meaning being unclear, then break with convention and do something so that it *is* clear. For instance, even though you would not normally use italics, if the specific name of the company makes it impossible to rephrase the sentence in such a way that it's clear the company name is a name, rather than a normal word or phrase, then use italics anyway. Just be consistent with whatever style you choose.

Comment: Wow, thanks for that very detailed answer! It didn't occur to me to use roman text — that would solve my problems and keep the client satisfied.